# error C3856: 'RecursiveType': symbol is not a class template

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I am trying to create type with recursive template like `std::tuple`, unfortunately it does not compile, however I did it seemingly same way as in `tuple` source code. I am compiling with Visual Studio 2022 with `-std:c++latest` and getting error `error C3856: 'RecursiveType': symbol is not a class template`.

Here is minimal example:

```
struct Param {
};

template <>
struct RecursiveType<> { // empty base case

};

template <Param T, Param... Rest>
struct RecursiveType<T, Rest...> : public RecursiveType<Rest...> { // recursive type definition

};
```

Comment: `std::tuple` is not recursive. The recursion you refer to was only necessary in old c++ standards. Rather than "how?" you should focus on the "what?". Anyhow, in your code you attempt to specialize a template before you declare the template, thats not possible

Comment: `template <>` is meant to specialize a template. But you didn't create the template to specialize, hence the `'RecursiveType' is not a class template` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a primary template. Both of your definitions are specializations.

```
template <Param... Params>
struct RecursiveType;
```

[See it on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Too9hPdPM)

Comment: Thanks! Interesting why in standard library code it is missing and working still?

Comment: @Somnium Are you sure it isn't somewhere you didn't see?

Comment: Not 100% of course, file is huge, I used search by `class tuple`, which resulted in 2 matches, similar to specializations I made. Maybe they defined it with some different syntax or in other file...

Comment: Right, it is [in another file](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/0403d19f5461fd15983737c3f01ec34800ea9275/stl/inc/utility#L140)

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the declaration for the primary template. The syntax you use are for specializations.

```
struct Param {
};

template <Param...>
struct RecursiveType; //The primary template must be declared

template <>
struct RecursiveType<> { // empty base case

};

template <Param T, Param... Rest>
struct RecursiveType<T, Rest...> : public RecursiveType<Rest...> { // recursive type definition

};
```

`RecursiveType` is a name. Before usage of any names, a declaration must be made to tell the compiler what it is. In this particular case, the declaration tells the compiler that `RecursiveType` is a template that takes arbitrary numbers of template parameters, and each parameter must be of type `Param`. Without the declaration, the compiler has no idea what the name refers to.

[Quote from the standard about explicit specialization](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.expl.spec)

> An explicit specialization does not introduce a name ([basic.scope.scope]). A declaration of a function template, class template, or variable template being explicitly specialized shall be reachable from the declaration of the explicit specialization.